# Extending an object ( nesting )

Tags: javascript

In a section object, I have a `CategoryId` - like a foreign key.
Now, I would like to copy each section into the matching category object.

Source:

```
var sections = [{title:"FirstSection", CategoryId : 1},
                {title:"SecondSection", CategoryId : 1}, 
                {title:"ThirdSection", CategoryId : 2}];
var categories = [{title:"Cat1", Id : 1},
                 {title:"Cat2", Id : 2}];
```

The result would look like this:

```
categories = [{title:"Cat1", 
               Id : 1, 
               sections : [{title:"FirstSection", CategoryId : 1},
                           {title:"SecondSection", CategoryId : 1}]
              },
              {title:"Cat2", 
               Id : 1, 
               sections: [{title:"ThirdSection", CategoryId : 2}]
              }];
```

All sections with `CategoryId = 1` are now in a sections array of the category with Id = 1.

Maybe I am searching for the wrong keywords, but I can not find a solution for this.

Comment: this is achieved with two simple for loops so what is your exact problem?

Comment: These are all arrays of objects, there is nothing in your code that has anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [supported](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.forEach) (>IE8 and all other browsers) this is easily done with...

```
categories.forEach(function(category) {
    category["sections"] = sections.filter(function(s) {
        return s.CategoryId === category.Id;
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4CMR/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I'd use the underscore library (you could do all this by hand).

http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

As you loop over the category array, you can easily do something like:

```
_.findWhere(sections, {categoryId: 1});
```

Furthermore with underscore you could:

```
var combined = _.groupBy(categories, function(cat){ 
    cat.sections = _.findWhere(sections, {CategoryId: cat.Id});
    return cat;
 });
```

And combined would have what you are looking for.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/kjkkV/1/

Comment: I like that functional approach. I was searching in the underscore-lib for this sort of function. Thank you!

Comment: The underscore library is quite awesome.